# How to solve an exception while attempting to evaluate a LINQ query parameter expression?

Tags: c#, angular, typescript

I have an error and i don't see a way to solve it.

I made an API call to filter by expired dates. Here it is:

```
[HttpPost, Route("/api/[controller]/GetExpiredDocuments")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetExpiredDocuments(ExpirationsCalendarFilterDTO filterEx)
        {
            List<Expiration> expirations = _expirationService.GetBy
            (e => e.Date < DateTime.Now && e.Document.FK_Company == filterEx.FK_Company
            && (filterEx.filterDoc.role == Role.ADMIN || e.Document.UserDocuments.Select(u => u.FK_User).Contains(filterEx.filterDoc.userID)) && e.isProcessed == false && e.Document.Archivia == false, e => e.Document);
            List<ExpirationDTO> expirationDTO = _autoMappingService.CurrentMapper.Map<List<ExpirationDTO>>(expirations);
            return Ok(expirationDTO);
```

When i try to call it here:

```
  expiredDocumentFilter: ExpirationDTO[];




openExpiredModal() {
    const expiredDocumentsFilter = new ExpirationsCalendarFilterDTO();

    this.expirationService
      .getExpiredDocuments(expiredDocumentsFilter)
      .subscribe((expiredDocuments: ExpirationDTO[]) => {
        this.expiredDocumentFilter = expiredDocuments;
        this.expiredModalRef = this.dialog.open(this.expiredModal, { width: "80%", height: "60%" });
      });
  }
```

The console shows me this error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)

ERROR Error: An exception was thrown while attempting to evaluate a LINQ query parameter expression. See the inner exception for more information. To show additional information call 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging'.
    at error.interceptor.ts:49:33
    at Observable.init [as _subscribe] (throwError.js:5:51)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:37:25)
    at Observable.js:31:30
    at errorContext (errorContext.js:19:9)
    at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:22:21)
    at catchError.js:14:31
    at OperatorSubscriber._error (OperatorSubscriber.js:23:21)
    at OperatorSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:40:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.mjs:1850:30)
handleError @ core.mjs:8416
```

I don't get it, I need for the datas to get showed on my table which is in the modal.

Comment: Can you provide the implementation for `GetBy` method?